# Can't access moskito-inspect webui

Tags: java

I am trying to use moskito-inspect tool in embedded mode, here is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <moskito.version>2.5.5</moskito.version>
    <moskito-central.version>1.1.0</moskito-central.version>
</properties>
...
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
                        <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems><artifactItem>
                    <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
                    <artifactId>moskito-webui</artifactId>
                    <version>${moskito.version}</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>moskito/**,**/*.jsp</includes>
                </artifactItem></artifactItems>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/tmp</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-web</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-webui</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-inspect-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-inspect-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.moskito</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-central-embedded-connector</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito-central.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.moskito</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-central-storages</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito-central.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I am running `maven clean install` I am getting war-file, which has the next inner structure:
[image]

When I deploy this war-file in tomcat, I can access my application by this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/ada
(where ada - application name)
```

so I have tried to access moskito-inspect webui by this URLs:

```
http://localhost:8080/ada/moskito
http://localhost:8080/moskito
http://localhost:8080/ada/mui
http://localhost:8080/mui
```

However, tomcat response for all these links in 404 [Not found].
What am I doing wrong, may be someone faced the same problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out that you should add to your `web.xml` Moskito filters configuration - like in [this article](https://confluence.opensource.anotheria.net/display/MSK/Embedding+Moskito-WebUI+Into+Your+Application).

But author also said in this article that

> With version 2.4.0 and servlet spec 3.0 no changes of the web.xml are
>   needed.

That's why I ignored that guide - very misleading advice!

Comment: Thanks for response, @Leon, I added moskito filters to my web.xml, and then it worked at http://localhost:8080/ada/mui/ =)